# 2006 Honda Civic door locks won't work when key is off

Tags: honda, civic, locks, electronics

We have a 2006 Honda Civic which has recently begun having an issue with the door locks. The power door locks will only work when the key is in the ON (II) position. If it's not in that position, then neither the key fob nor the master door lock switch (on the driver's door) will do anything at all. (Btw, I've also made sure that the doors are closed and it's in Park when I'm trying these things.)

I've checked both the fuse and the fob battery, though neither would explain why the master switch only works when the key is in II. And in any case, they're both fine. Any idea what else might be causing this?

Comment: Anything else not working that should with key off?

Comment: I noticed that I can't adjust the mirrors with the key off, which I thought I could do before. But I also know that the cigarette-lighter power plug works in ACC (I), just as it always did.